# Jquery from ouput element highlight matching element in table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to highlight 
Victor and Steve....(and other from #output if is change)

Html

```
<div id="output">Victor,Steve</div>
<table border="0">
    <tr><td>id</td><td>name</td><td>age</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>Victor</td><td>14</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>John</td><td>15</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>Steve</td><td>16</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td>Michael</td><td>17</td></tr>
    <tr><td>9</td><td>Michaela</td><td>20</td></tr>
</table>
```

jquery

```
var gg = $('#output').text();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tr').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('td').eq(1).text() == gg){
            $(this).css('background','red');
        }
    });
});
```

here the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/10tribu/wAxNu/964/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your jQuery to this:

```
var gg = $('#output').text().split(',');

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tr').each(function(){
            var getName = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text();
            if (jQuery.inArray(getName, gg) !== -1) {
            $(this).css('background','red');
        }
    });
});
```

That should solve it.

```js
var gg = $('#output').text().split(',');

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tr').each(function(){
      var getName = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text();
      if (jQuery.inArray(getName, gg) !== -1) {
         $(this).css('background','red');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output">Victor,Steve</div>
<table border="0">
    <tr><td>id</td><td>name</td><td>age</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>Victor</td><td>14</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>John</td><td>15</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>Steve</td><td>16</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td>Michael</td><td>17</td></tr>
    <tr><td>9</td><td>Michaela</td><td>20</td></tr>
</table>
```

This is converting the `gg` variable into an array of names and then inside the each function we're checking if the name is in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `includes()` to check if string contains sub-string.

```js
var gg = $('#output').text();

$('table tr').each(function() {
  if (gg.includes($(this).find('td').eq(1).text())) {
    $(this).css('background', 'red');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output">Victor,Steve</div>
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>age</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Victor</td>
    <td>14</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Steve</td>
    <td>16</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>Michael</td>
    <td>17</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>Michaela</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

A "functional" style solution

```
var gg = $('#output').text()
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tr').css('background', function(){
      return (gg.indexOf($(this).find('td').eq(1).text())>=0 )? 'red' : 'transparent';
    })
});
```